# I don't want the character "a" to be compared more than once if its already matched string comparison C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, for-loop, visual-c++

I have two strings:

```
string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string input = "abc";
```

You see how after the `i` loop executes, the first character of `abc_letters` is `'a'`, comparing that to the `j` loop character `input_letter` after it executes is also '`a'`, which is a match. That character gets stored into the `matched` string, which is what I want.

Now, the issue that I am having is that, by the second execution of the `j` loop, `abc_letters` remains `'a'` and `input_letter` becomes `'b'`, the characters don't match and `'a'` gets stored in the `missing` string, but `'b'` is a character in the `input` string, it just doesn't match the character `'a'`.

I need the `i` loop to move on to the next character after a letter is matched. In other words, `abc_letters` `'a'` character is a match and it gets stored into the `matched` string, the `i` loop should move on and `abc_letters` becomes `'b'`. If one character is already matched, I want the program to skip it, and not to compare it to other characters in the `input` string, that's clearly not gonna be a match!

I don't want the character `'a'` to be compared more than once and stored in both `missing` and `matched` strings if it's already matched.

Please help me modify this code in C++!

```cpp
string listMissingLetters(string input)
{
    string missing = "";  
    string matched = "";
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   
    bool letter_matched= true;//letters matched true or faulse 
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) 
    {
        letter_matched = true;
       char abc_letter = alphabet[i];//assigning the first character of the loops to the varible abc_letters
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) //nested loop for the user input string sorting through input string
        {
            char input_letter = input[j];//assigning the first character of the the input string to the varible input_letters
            if (abc_letter == input_letter) 
            {
                letter_matched = true;
                matched += abc_letter;
               
            }
            else if (abc_letter != input_letter)
            { 
                letter_matched = false;
                missing += abc_letter;
            }   
                   
        }     
    } 
    return missing;
}
```

Comment: Your description is not very clear to me. Try clarifying it a bit, and even better would be if you showed some input-output examples for the function.

Comment: 1) Do you want to check if all letters in your input string are alphabet letters? Then you don't need the outer loop; just walk your input string and check if each letter is in the alphabet string. Or 2) do you want to check if the input string is a substring of the alphabet string? Then you'd be done using `substr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you find a match, you need to `break` the `j` loop, so you can then `continue` the `i` loop.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
string listMissingLetters(string input)
{
    string missing, matched;
    const string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";   

    for (size_t i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); ++i) 
    {
        bool letter_matched = false;
        char abc_letter = alphabet[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); ++j)
        {
            char input_letter = input[j];
            if (abc_letter == input_letter) 
            {
                letter_matched = true;
                matched += abc_letter;
                break;               
            }
        }

        if (!letter_matched)
            missing += abc_letter;
    } 

    return missing;
}
```

Which can be simplified further if you replace the entire `j` loop with [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), eg:

```cpp
string listMissingLetters(string input)
{
    string missing, matched;
    const string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";   

    for (size_t i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); ++i) 
    {
        char abc_letter = alphabet[i];
        if (input.find(abc_letter) != string::npos)
            matched += abc_letter;
        else
            missing += abc_letter;
    } 

    return missing;
}
```

Which can then be simplified further if you get rid of `matched` and `alphabet`, since you don't really need them, eg:

```cpp
string listMissingLetters(string input)
{
    string missing;

    for (char abc_letter = 'a'; abc_letter <= 'z'; ++abc_letter) 
    {
        if (input.find(abc_letter) == string::npos)
            missing += abc_letter;
    } 

    return missing;
}
```

That being said, there are other ways to implement this task using standard algorithms so you don't have to hunt for the missing characters manually, eg:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

string listMissingLetters(string input)
{
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    alphabet.erase(
        std::remove_if(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end(),
            [&](char ch){ return (input.find(ch) != string::npos); }
        ),
        alphabet.end()
    );

    return alphabet;
}
```

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

string listMissingLetters(string input)
{
    const string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string missing;

    sort(input.begin(), input.end());
    set_difference(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end(), input.begin(), input.end(), back_inserter(missing));

    return missing;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/NYhLLq)

Comment: thank you the first example code was what I was looking for, can you explain this line for me  " if (!letter_matched)
            missing += abc_letter; " also how would I go about making this case sensitive to allow uppercase letter.  simplifying the first example code and thank you again I've been working on this for the longest!

Comment: @DavidsonCassagnol "*can you explain this line for me*" - really? What is unclear about it? I think it should be very self-explanatory. `letter_matched` is false unless the `j` loop finds a match. If no match is found, then `missing` is appended to. Are you maybe asking how [`operator!`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) works? "*how would I go about making this case sensitive*" - it already is. Maybe you meant case-**in**sensitive instead? Add uppercase letters to your `alphabet` string, otherwise use `strncmpi()` or equivalent function for comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to check to match each alphabet character to any character in "input", and mark it missing only if the alphabet character does not occur in "input" at all, then you need to modify your code a bit:

```
letter_matched = false;
char abc_letter = alphabet[i];       
for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++)
{
    char input_letter = input[j];
    if (abc_letter == input_letter) 
    {
         letter_matched = true;
         matched += abc_letter;
         break;
    }
}     
if( !letter_matched )
    missing += abc_letter;
```